# Within the organization, how to avoid being asked to interview others during the company's recruiting process?

Tags: recruiting

I've worked with a company for some time and we had a few interview seasons. I've participated in two of them so far. Anyways, since the pandemic, I've honestly felt less inclined (maybe lazy) to want to do any interviews any more. Anyways, they had a hold on the third interview season a few months ago and during that time I've become accustomed to my new work environment.

I never really liked interviewing and always found the process quite stressful. I also feel somewhat disconnected with the company so having to put my best face (or in this case best voice) has become a chore. Going through the company's dribble and trying to get people interested in the company, it just goes against my very nature if I've gotten somewhat less enthusiastic. In any case, this season we are getting set up to do interviews again but I have not drummed up the courage to excuse myself. Our organization is pretty large and we have over 100 people helping with interviews in the department alone.

I missed the training for the new interviewing process because I was too busy taking care of my day to day tasks, though I am familiar with my Organization's interviewing process, I imagine its quite similar to what we have done in the past but probably with a few modifications.

I don't really know how to excuse myself from interviewing this season. I don't really want to come off as disengaged although I know I am and at the same time I really don't want to let my organization down and not be 100% available to them. I'd really prefer if I get off the interviewer's list, I know its completely voluntary but excusing myself just seems like you have no company spirit or care about the organization, which just feels so selfish. Is there a way that I can communicate to the interview organizer's that I would like to excuse myself this year without sounding bad? Unfortunately, I just got scheduled to do an interview. I have been so busy that I forgot to send out a notice to please not schedule me but because I have so many conflictions I haven't communicated my intent so they scheduled me now. Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> has become a chore

Well, work isn't fun - that's kind of why they have to pay people to do it.

That said there's no harm in asking to be taken out of consideration to act as an interviewer - assuming it's not something that would be considered a core part of your role of course.

I'd probably avoid alluding to the reason being that you're feeling disillusioned or disengaged with the company or similar though, if you want to address that and rectify it (and it's probably worth doing if the situation continues) this isn't the way.

This:

> I missed the training for the new interviewing process because I was too busy taking care of my day to day tasks

Provides a couple of options though - you could say that you don't feel like you should be conducting interviews while your training is out of date, of course this might just lead them to either arrange catch-up training or say that it's not a problem. What is probably better is to focus on the second part - that you're busy with day to day tasks, and say that you feel that you need to be giving your main tasks and responsibilities your full focus at this point in time. After all this is *really* what they are paying you to be doing - and it protects you from accusations of being work-shy, since the reason you're bowing out of interviewing is so you can do *more* work.

Comment: Great! It worked! I even felt better enough to offer support next season. I think the thing that disillusioned me earlier is how my company shoehorns responsibility by not acknowledging you have choice. Its almost like they like to take control in this manner which prevents tutelage and mentorship. It felt nice when they listened, that it gave me the motivation to want to come back and help in the future when I feel more available to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not everybody is good at everything. You should talk to your manager and explain that you want to e left out from the interviewing, *if possible*.

As a reasoning, present the following:

- you had the initiative and good will to learn and to get involved and to make yourself useful;
- you found out that this is not really for you, *the way you see it*.

I learned that presenting hard decisions is not very easy to swallow. Leave the other person to make the decisions for you.

---

The worst case that I see is that your manager will not want to exclude you from interviewing. In this case you must make some decision about your life, and we cannot help you. Either you do it your way, and the boss gets angry, or you accept the boss's way and you remain angry.